# Combine queries based on number of results from first query

Tags: mysql

I am trying to combine 2 MySQL queries based on the number of rows returned in the first query, something like this:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `new_userprofile_combined`
WHERE `upg_featured` >= NOW() LIMIT 20
IF mysql_num_rows(1st query) < 20
(SELECT * FROM `new_userprofile_combined`
WHERE `upg_featured` < NOW() ORDER BY rand()
LIMIT (20-mysql_num_rows(1st query))) ");
```

Is this possible? How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql_num_rows();
```

Is a PHP function, not an SQL function, so you can not call it in a query, you will have to check the condition after the query, and then run another query.